# Ruby won't parse CSV when cell/field contains leading double quote

Tags: ruby, csv

How would I go about parsing a CSV file when one of the columns contains a double quote " character? 
Im getting the "Missing or stray quote in line xxx" error because there is a trailing double quote in it. The exact error is "Missing or stray quote in line 58 (CSV::MalformedCSVError)". The data is coming from an application that parses another device's (Firewall) config, and the " has been added as a comment to the configuration of this device by the admin, and is therefore beyond my control.

Example Input Data (can't provide the files, they are sensitive in nature):

```
"Table 1 Firewall Policy from INT to EXT administrative service rules on TestFirewall","1","Yes","Allow","[Group] GreenServer","[Host] Any","[Group] FTP","No",""Access"^M
```

As you can see, the comment in the last column is ""Access". The script I have so far appears to work perfectly well if there is just a double quote in the last column.

Minimum code required to replicate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'csv'
require 'pp'
nipperfiles = Dir.glob(ARGV[0] + '/*.csv')

def allcsv(nipperfiles)
  filearray = []
  nipperfiles.each do |csv|
  filearray << csv
  end

  filearray
end

def devicetype(filelist)
  filelist.each do |f|
  CSV.foreach(f, :headers => true, :force_quotes => true, :encoding => Encoding::UTF_8) do |row|
    if row["Table"] =~ /audit device list/ && row["OS"] =~ /FortiOS/
      return "Fortigate"
    end
    end
  end
end

filelist = allcsv(nipperfiles)
device = devicetype(filelist)
```

Ideally the working code would just ignore the extra quote or replace it or any other potentially problematic characters. It is probably worth noting that given the original Firewall config is configured by a person, that person could put the extra quote in just about any cell/field.

Comment: Whoops - There will also need to be a file containing: "Table","Device","Name","OS"
"Table 6 Security audit device list","Fortinet FortiGate Firewall","TestFirewall","FortiOS "

Comment: You CSV is malformed. Quotes within a strings need to be escaped. I suggest to fix this when writing the file, not when reading.

Comment: I don't have control over what the application does when writing the file.

Comment: Why don't you read as a tab delimited instead?... I guess this the way to go , unless it must be read as a csv.

Comment: You can't read a CSV file as TSV. TSV requires tabs between columns and CSV has commas between them.

Comment: If your data is malformed you should run a pre-flight check on it looking for known problems and fix them. Don't try to use CSV for that as it'll choke; Instead loop over the records using `File.foreach`, search for the issues, and replace them, then write the record to a new file. `gsub` and `sub` are usually good starting points.

Comment: Does anything occur after `^M` in the file? Does the field drop to the next line in the file and continue, or is it truncated?

Comment: @theTinMan Yes, this is just one line from the file(s). Looks like I'm either going to do the preflight checks as you suggest or play with the rescue option that was also posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a trick that may help.  Use `:quote_char => "'"` (assuming values in columns in CSV do not have single quote character), and this will include double quotes in the read values - which  you can get rid via code:

Example:

```
CSV.foreach(f, :force_quotes => true, :encoding => Encoding::UTF_8,
               :quote_char => "'") do |row|
   puts row[0]
   #=> "Table 1 Firewall ... administrative service rules on TestFirewall"
   puts row[0][1..-2]
   #=> Table 1 Firewall ... administrative service rules on TestFirewall
end
```

---

FYI: You could use any character that is least likely to appear in the CSV text as `:quote_char` and above solution will still work

---

If above does not work, then, you are better off processing each line as String and using `split` on it rather than using `CSV` class.

```
File.open("/path/to/file") do |f|
  f.each_line do |for|
    columns = row.split(",")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, there is data with single quotes in the input files.

Comment: @hatlord  Pick a char that is not likely to appear in CSV and above code should be helpful - for example, a unicode char like ♞

Comment: If I do this I get other errors. This is because there are newline/linebreaks inside of cells also. "Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n ". Unfortunately the  linebreaks within fields are required.

Comment: @hatlord May be you should not use CSV class, and use `File` class directly to read line by line and split each line by comma.

Comment: This may be what I end up doing unfortunately. The script is already written and working in 99% of cases, its just when people decide to add odd comments to the config.

Comment: Splitting lines on commas leads to madness if records contain text which happens to contain commas, especially multiple commas. The end result is rewriting chunks of the CSV class. It's often easier to pre-cleanse the data, fix what is a recognized problem, then pass it to the parser.

Answer (score 3):

You can rescue from `CSV::MalformedCSVError` and create separate handlers for lines with such problems, but this means you'll have to parse every line separately and you lose column names from the header line.

```
require 'csv'

File.open('csv.csv').each_line do |input_row|
  begin
    CSV.parse(input_row) do |row|
      puts row.inspect
    end
  rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError => error
    if input_row.include?('""')
      input_row.gsub!('""', '"')
      retry
    else
      raise error
    end
  end
end
```

I'm a bit surprised there isn't an option like `:on_malformed_csv => lambda ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Tin Man's idea proved the best, basically reading all the files in, changing the bits I didn't want. The script subsequently writes cleaned files that can be read by the CSV class. This allows me to add further substitutions in down the line if needed.

I chose to use [the Rio gem](http://rio.rubyforge.org) to get the job done.

Basic idea of the code:

```
cleanme = Dir.glob(ARGV[0])
def cleanfiles(cleanme)
  puts "Cleaning up CSV files"
  rio(cleanme).all.files('*.csv') do |f|
    puts "Reading and Cleaning File: #{f}"
    rio(f) <f.contents.gsub("''", "Empty").gsub(/""\w+"/, '"Comment Malformed and Removed"').gsub("\r\n", "\r")
  end
end
```

Wherever there was a malformed comment that threw an error I replaced with stray quote with the "Comment Malformed and Remove" line. This allows people in my team to cross reference back to the original input files and find out what the comment should have been. Any empty fields (techically "''") are replaced with the string "Empty".

Comment: You'll find this is necessary with CSV, TSV, HTML and XML on occasion. There are specs for these, however people ignore them, especially when they assume they understand the requirements. CSV is the most abused in my experience, though I've run into some horrible XML that failed to parse, and adjusting the text itself was required to get it to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to open file, read line by line and ignore first line

```
File.readlines("test.csv").drop(1).each do |line|
    CSV.parse(line) do |row|
        puts row.inspect
    end
end
```